# TYPO3 9.5.3 / Extbase: wrong timezone in backend and frontend

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have an extension with a gameday object which can have {n} games. For each game I have to set an datetime. When I select the Datetime all seems to be fine, also I a save the gameday. The datetime at the date field of the game is correct and also at the database, but the header of the game list item, which is the datetime of the game, has the wrong timezone. E.g. 10:00 19-01-2019 and header '19-01-2019 11:00'. At the frontend, the date is also wrong '19.01.2019 11:00' (format 'd.m.Y H:i').
I set the [SYS][phpTimeZone] to Europe/Berlin, which is my server timezone, but without any success.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a solution by myself, hope it will help someone else: I explicit set the [SYS][phpTimeZone] to UTC.